# What is the difference in Laravel Validation errors output?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am trying to output errors on my form validation using this two codes:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('/')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validator);
}
```

and

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('/')
        ->withErrors($validator);
}
```

they are doing exactly the same thing as what I'm trying to do with my application.
Can any body explain it why? if possible with reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will return same message. The difference only `withInput()`.

If you put `withInput()` statement it will return old value from form.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

If text username is invalid it will return the value back to the input.

If you didn't put `withInput()` it won't return anything. Only the validator message.

You can get more reference at here:

[Laravel Docs about old input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#old-input)

Comment: OK I got it! If I don't need the old value there is no reason to add the withInput() helper. This helped me understand @SSuhat
In my application I just need to out put the errors.

Comment: @MichaelAdam yes. if you don't need it there is no reason to add it. :) glad can help